# Android SDK instance error while opening Android device manager in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.1.3 with mobile development features. I am using AMD processor with Windows 10 with Virtualization Technology enabled in BIOS. Have also enabled hyper-v and Windows hypervisor platform. I have attached here all the images of my installation settings and error. Eagerly looking out for solutions and ideas.

[Android Options:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3kFz.png)

[Microsoft Supported Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6M68.png)

[Microsoft Supported Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fdg1.png), [Microsoft Supported Tools(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE9SV.png), [Microsoft Supported Tools(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHUp8.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XozuN.png)

Comment: Have you install the Android Emulator in Tools window which mentioned in the two screenshots (Microsoft Supported Tools(1), Microsoft Supported Tools(2)).

Comment: Yeah @WendyZang-MSFT I have installed android emulator version 28.0.25

Comment: Try to reinstall the SDK and install all the packages for Android 9.0 to create the emulator to test. And you could check the stpes in the link below. Maybe you miss someting. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows

Comment: Thank you @WendyZang-MSFT. I tried reinstalling the SDK. The issue still persist.

Comment: It seems everything is okay. Do you have another PC to test? I do not have the AMD processor to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you @WendyZang-MSFT. I was able to open Android device manager by running Visual Studio in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to open Android device manager by running Visual Studio in administrator mode.